# Google Analytics tracking in SharePoint 2007

Tags: web-analytics, google-analytics

I'm using SharePoint 2007 to run a website. I'd like to track downloads, outbound links, videos, etc. So far, i've read that event tracking can do this for me, but not sure where to place it since it comes with some javascript to plugin in the head of the page. I tried this and it threw back an error with the layout. Now I'm wondering if i should be dropping the javascript code in the master  or layout page for sharepoint. Has someone encountered this issue? 
Thanks in advance!
Nat

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to put the code into the head of the master page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any othe place i can place it? What if i only want to track outbound links for only one page in the whole site?

Comment: Then you could save the js code as a js file in a document library and add it to a page via the content link in a content editor web part.